# Electron net in Blazor webassembly project while adding project reference gives no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App error

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

In my blazor web assembly project when tried to add elctron net project reference, of version (13.5.1) getting following error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   NETSDK1082  There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.    BlazorElectronNet   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets   427

Below is the .csproj file where I added the reference

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ElectronNET.API" Version="13.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I am using.net6.can anyone please tell me how I can resolve this error?
Does .net6 supports electron-net for web assembly projects??